# Is there a way to change the NULL text of a NULLABLE report parameter to a CUSTOM TEXT

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdl

**Is there a way to change the NULL texts of a NULLABLE report parameter to CUSTOM TEXTS like is shown in folloing image ....** ?

[image]

I have read this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232432/ssrs-2005-how-to-change-the-label-of-the-null-checkbox-of-a-datepicker

And the proposed solution in this forum
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/879b0015-b053-40de-b97d-620fc283e542/how-to-change-null-label-of-the-checkbox-in-the-parameter-area

So I decided to create a Boolean Parameter called "Cualquier Hora Inicio" but is being rendered as two RADIO BUTTONS instead of ONE CHECKBOX (false = unchecked, true = checked)

[image]

**If the NULL text cannot be changed please let me know how can I force the Boolean parameter to be render a a checkbox and also to be located to the right and at the same height as the *Hora Inicio* parameter where is supposed to be**

Comment: Your only real option is to write a custom page that presents the parameters and renders the output in an iframe below it. You might be able to do something like inject some javascript that changes the text, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you absolutely have to have control of the parameters then write your own parameter page.

Comment: @JC the parameter page sounds great, do you have a link for that ? (please dont say google it ;-)

Comment: I can point you to the web service api, which lets you query the report service, list folders and report items, list parameters for reports, render reports to various formats, etc. You could use it to write a whole new web front-end to reporting services if you so desired. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx

Comment: @JC how about a Report processing extensions. These extensions enable the creation of custom report items managed by the report processing engine. They enable you to extend the Report Definition Language (RDL) standard to include functionality not natively supported by RDL, such as custom MapPoint maps and horizontal lists. You can also extend current report items to provide alternative versions that better fit your needs. as described here http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/custom-programming-enhance-ssrs-reports

Comment: I believe that's report functionality, not report server functionality. The parameters UI isn't part of the report. It's generated by the report server web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a custom assembly that overrides functionality of resources used by the ReportViewer control. You have to specify that your custom assembly be loaded instead of the default.

[Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/localization-asp-net-reportviewer-control-by-ReportViewerCustomMessages.aspx) is an article about implementing the IResource interface.

Comment: lrb thanks for the info, but it would be nice to have more detail and specific info about my original question