# How to change NULL label for checkbox to custom text in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, null

Is there a way to change the NULL label for a parameter in your report to your own custom text such as ON/OFF or anything?

[image]

I have seen only a few people come up with a barely practical solution of using an ASP.NET Web site project and then linking it to your report somehow but I'm not that technical to fully figure that out on my own.

Comment: unless you are rendering a custom page for this.. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Found this. Might be a solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919119/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-null-text-of-a-nullable-report-parameter-to-a-custo

Comment: Yeah that's what I had found before but I don't think I'm able to create an ASP.NET web site project at my work.